Chrome driver for Selenium Can not connect to the Service
Trying to use Selenium to click a DIV and return the resulting link that should appear afterwards
In Python I can get chrome to open but it eventually fails to get url with error  Can not connect to the Service D:\Software\chromedriver_126-win64\chrome.exe
for for what's worth here's my code
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

  ChromeDriverPath64 = "D:\\Software\\chromedriver_126-win64\\chrome.exe"

  s = Service(ChromeDriverPath64)
  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

  # keep it simple for now
  options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
  try:

      driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

      driver.get("https://www.python.org")
      print(driver.title)
  except Exception as e:
      print(e)

The Chromedriver matches Chrome version
Can any one see what I'm ding wrong

Running windows here, for me it runs with something like: "D:/Software/chromedriver_126-win64/chrome.exe", and after driver.get() I usually do html = driver.page_source and read with BeautifulSoup any tags or texts I need from that html.

I changed also the options and service definitions:
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() options.binary_location = "C:/folder/to/chrome/chrome-win64/chrome.exe" service = Service(executable_path="C:\\folder\\to\\selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")

Changing "\" to "/" service = Service(executable_path="C:\\folder\\to\\selenium\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe") didn't make any difference nor did adding options.binary_location = "C:/folder/to/chrome/chrome-win64/chrome.exe"  (assuming you mean the location of standard Chrome.exe

In your original post, you provide a filepath to chrome.exe--that is the name of the Chrome executable, not of Chromedriver (which is chromedriver.exe). Make sure you download the right file (AFAIK they are all on one page in a big list, making it easy to confuse them). Are you saying that after providing the path to chromedriver.exe to Service it is still not working?

@ryyyn Thank you it looks like I was confusing chrome.exe for chromedriver.exe it's now working I can now move on.

in the newest Selenium you don't need to set path to driver because it can download it automatically from internet. So you need only webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
